# Отладка Json файлов

Tags: android, json, http, get, https

Есть приложение на android, которое отправляет на сервер GET запрос с определенными параметрами для доступа. На этот запрос оно получает в качестве ответа Json файл.
Есть ли способ мне получить этот json файл, когда он придёт?

Comment: Отправить такой же запрос самому не вариант?

Comment: @woesss Возможно, но это сложнее

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я использовал `Fiddler`, статей, как настроить его, достаточно. Если хотите сниффить https, нужно будет заморочиться с сертификатом, и не факт, что поможет.

Comment: Я тоже использую фиддлер, в нём вижу нужный запрос и ответ. Но, мне интересно, **я могу где-нибудь найти файл который пришел или нет**?

Comment: @avalanche_of_misery, Вы хотите перехватить этот json в своём андроид-приложении?

Comment: @woesss, к сожалению нет. Если бы в своём, все было бы проще

Comment: @avalanche_of_misery, я имел ввиду, что Вы в своём приложении хотите перехватить json другого приложения, то есть средствами Андроида?

Comment: @woesss Да! Как-то так

Comment: @avalanche_of_misery, тогда проще подделать запрос и послать самому. Без рута вряд ли можно сделать что-то ещё. Тут нужно сниффер или прокси встраивать в приложение, слушать весь траффик в вечном сервисе и идентифицировать нужный пакет из всего барахла. Можно ещё попытаться порыться в приватных папках приложения, если Вам нужна какая-то информация, а не именно этот пакет с сервера.

Comment: @woess, Вы правы. Но, когда я отправляю запрос, сервер даёт access denied. Хотя мой запрос идентичен с тем, который формирует приложение https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/813325/long-poll-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80

Comment: В общем-то задача вообще не простая - я с ВК не работал, но скорее всего у них такая же система. Каждому приложению выдаются уникальные ключи, с помощью которых по формуле вычисляется подпись для каждого запроса и передаётся в заголовках. Сервер пересчитывает подпись дубликатом ключа и сверяет с присланной. Нужно реверсить приложение и смотреть как оно формирует запросы.