# Long Poll сервер

Tags: android, vkontakte-api, http, https, long-poll

Есть андроид приложение. Когда я его запускаю, оно получает access_token. Приложение с помощью него успешно обращается к Long poll серверу через message.getLongPollServer и получает key и ts. **Почему, когда я, в браузере, отправляю такой же запрос, сервер выдаёт мне access denied ? Можно ли как-то отправить серверу такой же запрос и получить нужные мне данные?**
Запрос в приложении и в браузере я формирую один и тот же:

> https://api.vk.com/method/messages.getLongPollServer?access_token=123456789&need_pts=0&Ip_version=2&version=5.73&https=1
>   <
>   [image: Ответ от сервера]

Comment: Покажите как именно в коде делаете вызов и как именно его в браузере делаете

Comment: Скорее всего запросы отличаются , я бы посоветовал вам использовать приложение Postman, там можно выбрать тип авторизации и подставить токен.

Comment: Ключ доступа тот же самый? Возможно права нужные не запросили при его получении.

Comment: Смотрите внимательно заголовки - что-то Вы не учли. И я почти уверен, что запросы к апи должны осуществляться после аутентификации юзера.